# Read Image from SQL Server VarBinary(Max)

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have a SQL Server Database. I have stored an image in there which is a varbinary(max). I inserted the image the following way :

```
string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString);
            con.Open();

            String filePath = fuImage.PostedFile.FileName;
            String naam = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            String extension = Path.GetExtension(naam);

            Stream stream = fuImage.PostedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream);
            Byte[] imgByte = br.ReadBytes((Int32)stream.Length);


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "spAddImage";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FOTO", imgByte);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ARTIEST", ddlArtiest.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

The image now looks like this in the database : 
It is stored as a varbinary.

http://puu.sh/ikF83/6a03b52520.png <--- database

Now I want to display my image on my asp.net page that I have inserted.

But I have no idea how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `SqlDataReader` to go over the results and get back what you need

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
  byte[] myImage = (byte[])reader["MyImageColumn"];
}
```

This is from top of my head so make your adjustments as required. But it should give you the basic idea.

Furthermore, It's strongly recommended to use the `using` block as it ensures the object is disposed correctly.

So you could change your code to

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  //Your command 
  connection.Open();

  //Datareader here

}//Object disposed here
```

Reference to [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Reference to [using block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I should get alone with this :)! but where do I display my image in then? In a control or?

Comment: Display it according to your requirement.. e.g you could use `<asp:Image />` or `<asp:GridView />`  and within the grid you can use `<asp:ImageField />` the choice is pretty much yours.

Comment: Now working on it. I'll keep you posted :)! Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't really get errors. Just can't figure out how to use your code. I don't have enough reputation to chat with you.. is there a way I can contact you? Skype or something?

Comment: Don't use `AddWithValue()` either.

Comment: What part don't you understand exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer provided by Izzy, below is how we have implemented the same.

```
public HttpResponseMessage RenderImage(RenderRequest renderRequest, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();

    try
    {
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            byte[] imagebytes = (byte[])reader["MyImageColumn"];
        }

        return httpResponse = request.CreateResponse<byte[]>(HttpStatusCode.OK, imagebytes, new ImageMediaFormatter("image/png"));
    }
    catch ()
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```