# Convert Varbinary To upload Image MVC asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Hy master I have some problem when I convert Image `varbinary(MAX)`
 I have a procedure like this

```
Create Procedure SelectBarang   
as     
Begin    
    Select * from Barang;    
End
```

and i have class model like this

```
public class ShopDB
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ShopEntities"].ConnectionString;

    public List<Barang> ListAll()
    {
        List<Barang> lst = new List<Barang>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        //using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SelectBarang", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                lst.Add(new Barang
                {
                    IdBarang = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["IdBarang"]),
                    NamaBarang = rdr["NamaBarang"].ToString(),
                    Harga = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Harga"]),
                    CategoriId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["CategoriId"]),
                    GambarBarang = Convert  ??                            
                });
            }
            return lst;
        }
    }
}
```

How I can change `varbinary` to image for Add my data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Image from SQL Server VarBinary(Max)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778311/read-image-from-sql-server-varbinarymax)

Comment: i not dulicate that @NightOwl888

Comment: What is the data type for GambarBarang?

Comment: Hi you can take as byte array and convert to image document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = "data:image/png;base64," + YourByte;

Comment: @JujurSitanggang - You may not have intentionally copied the other question, and that is understandable. But the purpose of StackOverflow is to try to provide a canonical question and answer for a given question. It is your responsibility to make sure the question has not been previously asked and adequately answered on StackOverflow before asking it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can do something like

1. you can read data using:

   ```
    byte[] myImage = (byte[])reader["MyImageColumn"];
   ```
2. Then use this in mvc view

   ```
   @{
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ByteArray);
    var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
   }
   ```