# Retrieve an image from folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to retrieve an image from folder using MVC C#, and display cell of datatables?

We have captured image through Android saved in one folder on server like `D:/Image_Upload`.

```
"aoColumns": [

               { data: 'ProjectNo' },
               { data: 'FarmerGID' },
               { data: 'FarmerName', 'sWidth': '20%' },
               { data: 'Contact' },
               { data: 'CapacityDesc' },
               { data: 'Unit_Code' },
               { data: 'Unit_Desc' },
               { data: 'VillageCode' },
               { data: 'Village Name', 's Width': '15%' },

               { data: 'SurveyStatus', 'sWidth': '15%', "render": function (data) {

                return '<img width="25px" height="25px" src="file:/D:/Image_Uploa/xyz.jpg">';
               }
               }
            ],
```

We are getting image box in output, but not able to display the image.

[image]

Comment: convert the image text to MvcHtmlString

Comment: i think my answer will work. Make sure image exist the path

Comment: Thanks Nayas, still working on this

Comment: please mark it as answer if it helps you

Comment: @kumarh browser wont be able to resolve this path `src="file:/D:/Image_Uploa/xyz.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use do something like this to convert string to IHtmlString.

Make sure image path is correct

```
@Html.Raw("<img width='25px' height='25px' src='file:/D:/Image_Uploa/xyz.jpg'>")

@Html.Raw("<span>hi</span>")
```

In your case you can use

```
@Html.Raw(model.SurveyStatus)
```

Comment: HI How to convert system.byte[] to image in Javascript, i am getting data from c# like System.byte[] displaying

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44252963/convert-varbinary-to-upload-image-mvc-asp-net/44253255#44253255

Comment: please up the value if it helps you

Comment: hi,  byte[] imgg = (byte[])(oRow["Log_Snap"]);
                            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imgg, 0, imgg.Length);
                            oUnitData.imgdisp = "data:image/PNG;base64," + base64String;